# How to disable submit button after click single time

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want to disable submit button once it has clicked for send.this is my submit button code

```
<button title="<?PHP echo getTranslatedString('LBL_SAVE_ALT'); ?>" accessKey="S" class="btn btn-primary" value="<?PHP echo getTranslatedString('LBL_SAVE_LAPTOP'); ?>" id="formSave" type="submit" name="button" onclick="return checkform();">
```

Save detail

and this is onclick function code

```
function checkform() {
var incvfr = $("#invoice").val();
var inseridf = $("#invserial").val();
if (incvfr == 1) {
    if (inseridf == '') {
        alert("Please enter invoice number");
        return false;
    }
} else {
    document.save.submit();
    document.getElementById('formSave').setAttribute("disabled", "disabled");
}
}
```

when i disable submit button then form not send for save just disable button how to do it.
when i use disable code after `save.submit();` then form submit but save button not disable

Comment: are you redirecting back from the page submission?

Comment: No when i click save details there is no effect in form just disable button but i want to send form

Comment: *"Hello sir"*. Good afternoon madam.

Comment: I don't know whether you're comfortable using php to keep a button disable after refresh, However here's a solution in JS http://stackoverflow.com/a/22279996/5336321

Answer (score 4):

Try `one()` method in jQuery, it will run once for an element and might simplify your code.

**jQuery Solution:**

```js
$(function(){
  $('#formSave').one('click', function() {  
    $(this).attr('disabled','disabled');
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input title="" accessKey="S" class="btn btn-primary" value="Save detail" id="formSave" type="submit" name="button" onclick="">
```

**JavaScript Solution:**

Use `setAttribute()` method.

```js
function disable(){
  document.getElementById('formSave').setAttribute("disabled", "disabled"); 
}
```

```html
<input title="" accessKey="S" class="btn btn-primary" value="Save detail" id="formSave" type="submit" name="button" onclick="disable()">
```

Answer (score 0):

As I can see that you re using jQuery so when you are saving after that you can use jQuery hide function to hide your button by passing button id

```
function checkform(){
  var incvfr=$("#invoice").val();
var inseridf=$("#invserial").val();
  if(incvfr== 1) {
  if(inseridf==''){
    alert("Please enter invoice number");
    return false;
    }
} else {
    document.save.submit();
$("#formSave").hide();
}
 }
```

Comment: i dont want to hide save button just wanted to disable.

Answer (score 0):

You can disable submit button using

```
$("#formSave").attr('disabled',true);
```

or

```
$("#formSave").prop('disabled',true);
```

Answer (score 0):

add property disable

```
$("#formSave").prop('disabled',true);
```

if you want revert it use

```
$("#formSave").prop('disabled',false);
```

Comment: when i use  $("#formSave").prop('disabled',true); after document.save.submit(); then button disable but form not submt